# Notifications suspended?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I observed in the last 24 hours the following two bugs.

1. I did not get the usual red banner notification when the reputation count surpassed a privilege limit.
2. Also I by chance discovered a comment under a recent question, which was addressed in the standard way "@user" (without spelling-mistakes!) to me, but it did not show up in my "response list", nor did I get the usual red notification icon on top of the page.

Are others having the same bug?

Comment: Not that I've noticed. But then...

Comment: @dmckee. Well, strange. Now it works. I was notified about your above comment.

Comment: I've been getting notifications as usual, I didn't notice any interruption. Maybe it was just a temporary glitch :/

Comment: That happens to me once in a while too . .  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not aware of any issues with responses at this time, and have no other reports of this network-wide AFAIK.

Comment: Dear @Jeff Atwood. I have not experienced any break in notifications since the above mentioned 24 hour period. I was, e.g., notified about this answer, and have received others as well.